# How to add required validation mat-error to mat-list in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a requirement to show list items in the form
that list items should be loaded from the input field by users.
While submitting the form if the list is empty then the form should show an error message.

[image]

Stackblitz [Example codebase](https://angular-material-starter-6hdhpj.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Please share more details to your question. What have you tried and if possible share the code using some editor.

Answer (score 0):

When I look your code.
The html code is correct, but you have not declared the variable submitted in the .ts file.

So you just have to add one variable in .ts file as shown below:

```
submitted:boolean=false
```

And when you call the method **createNewTask()**, you just add this line in that method.

```
 createdNewTask(){
    this.submitted= true;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, My question is how to add formController to <mat-list>. Because i want to use the data which is available in <mat-list> after form submission. So that should not be empty. and we can also use in-built check for is form valid or not by using this this.addForm.valid

Answer (score 0):

I am changing the logic by using "mat-chip" and horizontal chip list instead of ""mat-list"
So that is how i can add formController attribute and form validation